# Travelling from EZE (Buenos Aires, Argentina) to the Retiro Bus terminal

Tags: airport-transfer, buenos-aires, eze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to get from the airport to center of Buenos Aires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3990/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-from-the-airport-to-center-of-buenos-aires)

I am going to be travelling in Argentina and need to get from Ezeiza (the EZE airport) to the Retiro Bus Terminal. I speak very little Spanish though will be working on it between now and my trip.

What is recommended as the easiest/safest way for a non-Spanish-speaking tourist to get to the Bus Terminal?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel.Se. Great question, but I believe this has been asked before. I'll add this as a duplicate.  Enjoy it, it's a great country, even with little Spanish skills you'll find it fine to get around.